# Samsung galaxy s3 vibrate

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, vibration

I have had my phone for a while and I am always feeling guilty because I haven't replied to text message that I never knew that I got when I have my phone on vibrate. It only vibrates when I pick it up or move it, it's not like my old phone like when you get a message it vibrated automatically but my samsung galaxy s3 doesn't.

Is there anyway that I could have it like that so it doesn't only vibrate when I move it?

Comment: If you go to your Messaging app's settings, is there an option for vibrating alerts or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you look under sound settings there should be an option for vibration patterns. The intensity should be configurable from there as well.